# Update single table using key field

Tags: mysql

I've tried to do the following between two tables without succes and trying to do in one now.

Locations table with zips, city, state, name (one of the three first fields) and type (city, state, zip

Trying to create parent fields e.g. Zip would have it's city as parent

So looking to do something like

For each record where type is zip, find a record with the same city, state where type is city and make that ID it's parentID

For each record where type is city, find a record with the same city, state where type is state and make that ID it's parentID

Comment: You really have to show some sample data of those tables and maybe a desired output table to make it easier to help

Comment: Yeah not sure how to format here sorry :( I'll take a look at that link

Comment: I can't make sense of that. Maybe you should create an [sqlfiddle](www.sqlfiddle.com) with the sample tables and some data.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct but
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df4b9/2/0

Comment: Were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE temp_demo_loc AS a
INNER JOIN temp_demo_loc AS b ON a.City = b.City
SET a.ParentID = b.id
WHERE a.Type = 'Zip' AND b.Type = 'City';

UPDATE temp_demo_loc AS a
INNER JOIN temp_demo_loc AS b ON a.City = b.City
SET a.ParentID = b.id
WHERE a.Type = 'City' AND b.Type = 'State';
```

And do the same for the next levels.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7a54/1)</kbd>